# Too much fluctuation in F1 Score curve during meta training with MAML

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, meta-learning, few-shot-learning, learn2learn

I am training `VGG11` on a custom image dataset for 3-way 5-shot image classification using `MAML` from `learn2learn`. I am encapsulating the whole `VGG11` model with `MAML`, i.e., not just the classification head. My hyperparameters are as follows:

- Meta LR: 0.001
- Fast LR: 0.5
- Adaptation steps: 1
- First order: False
- Meta Batch Size: 5
- Optimizer: AdamW

During the training, I noticed that after taking the first outer-loop optimization step, i.e., `AdamW.step()`, loss skyrockets to very large values, like ten thousands. Is this normal? Also, I am measuring the micro F1 score as accuracy metric of which curve for meta training/validation is as follows:
[image: Meta Train/Val F1 Score curve]

It is fluctuating too much in my opinion, is this normal? What could be the reason of this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was using `VGG11` with vanilla `BatchNorm` layers from PyTorch which was not working properly in meta training setup. I removed `BatchNorm` layers and now it works as expected.